# insertAfter for more than one div

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following section of  script

```
.on('finish.countdown', function(event) {
        $(this).text("<?php echo TEXT_SHIPPING_BARELY_PAST_DISPATCH; ?>").parent().addClass('disabled');
    }) .insertAfter('#cartDefaultHeading');
```

I want the same output to appear after more than one div across a couple of different pages. If I change the div name it appears in a new location as expected.
But if I try to get it to appear on more than one I don't get any output.

I tried the following

```
.on('finish.countdown', function(event) {
        $(this).text("<?php echo TEXT_SHIPPING_BARELY_PAST_DISPATCH; ?>").parent().addClass('disabled');
    }) .insertAfter('#cartDefaultHeading').insertAfter('#checkoutOrderHeading');
```

and

```
.on('finish.countdown', function(event) {
    $(this).text("<?php echo TEXT_SHIPPING_BARELY_PAST_DISPATCH; ?>").parent().addClass('disabled');
}) .insertAfter('#cartDefaultHeading'), .insertAfter('#checkoutOrderHeading') ;
```

and even

```
.on('finish.countdown', function(event) {
    $(this).text("<?php echo TEXT_SHIPPING_BARELY_PAST_DISPATCH; ?>").parent().addClass('disabled');
}) .insertAfter('#cartDefaultHeading');
    $(this).text("<?php echo TEXT_SHIPPING_BARELY_PAST_DISPATCH; ?>").parent().addClass('disabled');
}) .insertAfter('#checkoutOrderHeading');
```

None worked. Whenever I try to get it on more than one div I get it on neither.
What's the correct syntax to achieve this?

The complete script is shown below:

```
<script>
jQuery(function($){
if (($('#cartDefaultHeading').length || $('#checkoutOrderHeading').length) && !$('.checkout_dispatch_timer').length) {
    var $this = $('<div class="checkout_dispatch_timer <?php echo $dispatch_countdown_timer_style; ?>"></div>');
    <?php if ($dispatch_countdown_timer_disable === false) { ?>
    var finalDate = moment.tz('<?php echo $dispatch_countdown_timer_date_array[4]; ?>', '<?php echo date_default_timezone_get(); ?>');
    $this.countdown(finalDate.toDate())
    .on('update.countdown', function(event) {
        var format = '%Mm';

        if (event.offset.totalDays > 0) {
            format = '%Dd:%Hh:' + format;
        } else if (event.offset.totalHours > 0) {
            format = '%Hh:' + format;
        } else {
            format = format + ':%Ss';
        }

        dispatch_countdown_timer_text = "<?php echo $dispatch_countdown_timer_text; ?>";
        dispatch_countdown_timer_text = dispatch_countdown_timer_text.replace('%s', event.strftime(format));

        $(this).text(dispatch_countdown_timer_text);

    })
    .on('finish.countdown', function(event) {
        $(this).text("<?php echo TEXT_SHIPPING_BARELY_PAST_DISPATCH; ?>").parent().addClass('disabled');
    }) 
    .insertAfter('#cartDefaultHeading');
<?php } else { ?>
    $this.text("<?php echo $dispatch_countdown_timer_text; ?>").insertAfter('#checkoutOrderHeading');
<?php } ?>
}
});
</script>
```

Comment: What are you trying to insert? The element that's being inserted is the element before `.on()`, not the text that you're echoing.

Comment: @Barmar It's inserting the time calculated by moment.js based on a value set in the database. It also builds a specific message depending on the amount of tile left. The message content in in the var $dispatch_countdown_timer_text

Comment: The way you've written it, `insertAfter` happens when the page is loaded, not when the event occurs. Is that what you want?

Comment: Yes. When someone loads the shopping cart page it should display the counter above the cart contents, and when they enter the checkout process it should show above the payment fields etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use `.insertAfter()` multiple times, because each one will remove the element from the previous location before trying to insert it after the next one. Use `.after`.

```js
$('#cartDefaultHeading, #checkoutOrderHeading').after(
  $this.countdown(finalDate.toDate())
  .on('update.countdown', function(event) {
    var format = '%Mm';

    if (event.offset.totalDays > 0) {
      format = '%Dd:%Hh:' + format;
    } else if (event.offset.totalHours > 0) {
      format = '%Hh:' + format;
    } else {
      format = format + ':%Ss';
    }

    dispatch_countdown_timer_text = "<?php echo $dispatch_countdown_timer_text; ?>";
    dispatch_countdown_timer_text = dispatch_countdown_timer_text.replace('%s', event.strftime(format));

    $(this).text(dispatch_countdown_timer_text);

  })
  .on('finish.countdown', function(event) {
    $(this).text("<?php echo TEXT_SHIPPING_BARELY_PAST_DISPATCH; ?>").parent().addClass('disabled');
  })
);
```

This assumes that any page only has one of `#cartDefaultHeading` and `#checkoutOrderHeading`, because you can't insert the same element in multiple places (`.after` and `.insertAfter` don't make a copy, it moves the element itself).

Comment: That resulted in no output at either of the divs. I've edited the original question to show the entire script , but have excluded the php code that's also there.

Comment: Updated the answer

Comment: That works perfectly for the main timer event.
I assume i'm going to have the same issue adding the expired message which is output by the end of the code above in this section:

<?php } else { ?>
    $this.text("<?php echo $dispatch_countdown_timer_text; ?>").insertAfter('#checkoutOrderHeading');
<?php } ?>

Comment: If you're not trying to insert after two different locations, you can use either. You only need this for multiple insert places.

Comment: They both need to appear in multiple locations. The code originally only needed to display it in one place, but I decided to show it on two different pages after it was implemented.

Comment: Then do it the same way. Why would be any different?

Comment: Based on how you changed the original text, I modified the else statement to

<?php } else { ?>
  $('#cartDefaultHeading, #checkoutOrderHeading').after(
  $this.text("<?php echo $dispatch_countdown_timer_text; ?>")
  );
<?php } ?>

Works perfectly, and I learned something. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

According the to the docs, you can pass an array of elements to the function.
Source: http://api.jquery.com/insertafter/

```
`insertAfter(['#cartDefaultHeading','#checkoutOrderHeading']);
```

Comment: Just tried that, and whilst I get the background colour of the div it should be adding, #cartDefaultHeading has no text content, whilst #checkoutOrderHeading does.
If i switch the order to insertAfter(['#checkoutOrderHeading','#cartDefaultHeading']) the page the output is displayed on changes. So it would appear that the text content is only applied to the last div in the insertAfter command, even though the div is set on both.